# Plasmashell deleting file it's very slow

Tags: kde, plasma, plasma5

This is the OS:

- Kubuntu 16.04 (fresh install but with the home folder from my old
  14.04 installation)
- KDE Plasma vesion: 5.5
- OS Type: 64 bit
- Kernel: 4.4.0-51

After restart I try to remove file from the desktop. The delete process takes about 2 to 3 minutes (takes about 14% CPU of my i7). This is for all kinds of files. I delete the file just with right click and 'Move to trash' option. After the first delete the other deletes are OK and happen immediately. I tried to remove my .kde folder , so that is recreated from the OS. This did not work as well. I cannot create new user because I have many configurations for this user. I don't know if this is the right place for such question because this is bug and not question to learn from.

Probably this guy have the same problem , but he didn't wait enough to see if the file is deleted or not:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnVWmAFPOeA

Comment: This happens not only after restart. It's in random moment really. How can I track the problem

Comment: Don't know if this is true solution or not , but here is what worked: Go to /home/username/.local/share/Trash/files and $sudo rm -R ./*

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because kde treats all drives as external except those which are mounted through fstab configuration.

You have to configure all of your drives trough fstab so that they'll mount directly during boot. Then kde treats them as internal drives & adds Trashes in their respective root directories.

Get UUIDs of your drives using **sudo blkid**, then add these lines to /etc/fstab using a text editor (you'll need root permissions)

UUID=01D4F3BE34259100  /mnt/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=077  0 0
UUID=440A9FBF0A9FAD04  /mnt/Windows  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=077  0 0

& before adding the above lines you have to create directories in mnt by **mkdir**